# Partial Search using spring boot and MongoDB as a database

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

I am trying to implement partial search. For that I have added regex also. But it's not working.If whole word is matching then only it's returning the matching contents.

```
public <T> Page<T> partialSearch(Class<T> t, SearchRequest request) {
String partialSerchKey = ".*"+request.getSearchKey()+".*";
TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(partialSerchKey);
Criteria searchCriteria = buildCriteria(request.getSessionProfile().getCompanies().get(0), request.getFilterModel());
Query textQuery = Query.query(searchCriteria).addCriteria(criteria);
Sort sort = getSortModel(request.getSortModel());
log.debug("SORT : {}",sort);
int pageSize = request.getEndRow() - request.getStartRow();
int pageIndex = (request.getEndRow() / pageSize)-1;

log.debug("Page Index : {}, Page Size : {}", pageIndex, pageSize);
Pageable paging = (sort == null)? PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize) : PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize, sort);
Page<T> irPage = PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(zportDBTemplate.find(textQuery.with(paging), t),
paging,
() -> 0);
return irPage;
}
```